# Inquiry regarding Password Tab?

Tags: apache, drupal, authorization, user-experience

How would I go about creating a link that contains confidential information specific to the user and when clicked, it would open up a tab that requires authorization in order to access the information.

I've been given advice to use Apache and Drupal but I'm not sure how to start things. Any form of advice would be GREATLY appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Shield](https://www.drupal.org/project/shield) module of Drupal for your purpose.

OR

You should be able to do this using the combination of mod_env and the Satisfy any directive. You can use SetEnvIf to check against the Request_URI, even if it's not a physical path. You can then check if the variable is set in an Allow statement. So either you need to log in with password, or the allows you in without password:

```
//Do the regex check against the URI here, if match, set the "require_auth" var
SetEnvIf Request_URI ^/your/url require_auth=true

// Auth stuff
AuthUserFile /var/www/htpasswd
AuthName "Password Protected"
AuthType Basic

//Setup a deny/allow
Order Deny,Allow

//Deny from everyone
Deny from all

//except if either of these are satisfied
Satisfy any

1. a valid authenticated user
Require valid-user

or 2. the "require_auth" var is NOT set
Allow from env=!require_auth
```